# mrt create child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

when I run the following command: **mrt create app**
the propmt returns this message

**child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.**

achoque: created.

To run your new app:
  cd app
  meteor

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LST

Meteor --version: 1.0.3.2

Meteorite --version: 0.9.3

node --version: v0.13.0-pre

npm --version: 2.5.1

what does that mean?

Comment: Why you use meteorite? `meteor create app` -> `cd app` -> `meteor run`

Comment: upgrade to the latest meteor version, you may no more need mrt

Comment: `Meteor --version: 1.0.3.2` it is latest version of meteor

Comment: i understand, with last version of meteor i dont need the mrt, thanks.